# How to make Terminal suggest custom command's option?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, console

I'm a Kubuntu user.

If i type

**$ apt-get (tab)**

on Terminal, Shell suggests options:
autoclean, build-dep, check, ..., clean, download, install, remove, update

If I want to use custom command with options using either an alias or a shell script in paths, how can I make Terminal (or Shell) suggest options?

E.g., the command is 'myclock' and its options are 'us' and 'korea.'

If I type

**$ myclock korea**

-> (print Korea time)

If I type

**$ myclock us**

-> (print U.S. time)

How can I make Terminal suggest options ('us' or 'korea') when I type

**$ myclock (tab)**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a custom alias via .bash_profile or for kubuntu .profile

sudo in to root and use a text editor of your choice. I prefer vi but you can use nano!

```
 sudo -i
  root@server vi .profile
```

your profile by default should look like this

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n
```

so now to add an alias. you can name your alias anything! heres a custom alias for .profile that I use. I work in SF and live in Oakland so the weather can be slightly different so i created a custom alias to curl for weather

```
alias weatherSF="curl -s 'http://rss.accuweather.com/rss/liveweather_rss.asp?metric=1&locCode=en|us|san-francisco-ca|94103' | sed -n '/Currently:/ s/.*: \(.*\): \([0-9]*\)\([CF]\).*/\2°\3, \1/p'"
alias weatherOak="curl -s 'http://rss.accuweather.com/rss/liveweather_rss.asp?metric=1&locCode=en|us|Oakland-ca|94612' | sed -n '/Currently:/ s/.*: \(.*\): \([0-9]*\)\([CF]\).*/\2°\3, \1/p'"
```

now notice if you try tabbing it wont work.. so what you need to do is

```
source ~/.profile
```

after source you should be able to tab your new alias!

if youre interested in other alias here are some other examples

```
alias myip='curl ip.appspot.com'                    # myip:         Public facing IP Address
alias netCons='lsof -i'                             # netCons:      Show all open TCP/IP sockets
alias flushDNS='dscacheutil -flushcache'            # flushDNS:     Flush out the DNS Cache
alias lsock='sudo /usr/sbin/lsof -i -P'             # lsock:        Display open sockets
alias lsockU='sudo /usr/sbin/lsof -nP | grep UDP'   # lsockU:       Display only open UDP sockets
alias lsockT='sudo /usr/sbin/lsof -nP | grep TCP'   # lsockT:       Display only open TCP sockets
alias ipInfo0='ipconfig getpacket en0'              # ipInfo0:      Get info on connections for en0
alias ipInfo1='ipconfig getpacket en1'              # ipInfo1:      Get info on connections for en1
alias openPorts='sudo lsof -i | grep LISTEN'        # openPorts:    All listening connections
alias showBlocked='sudo ipfw list'                  # showBlocked:  All ipfw rules inc/ blocked IPs
```

[check this website for some tips](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/create-aliases-in-bash-profile-to-assign-shortcuts-for-common-terminal-commands/)